# Is there any downside to checking if the first element of an array exists as a condition, rather than checking if it's length is greater than zero?

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax

When ever I have to check if an array has elements in it I always default to checking its length for example...

```
const array = [];

if (array.length > 0) do something...
```

However today I thought couldn't I just check if the zero index of the array is not undefined rather than checking the length, I find this saves some typing?

```
// if the zero index element exists

if (array[0]) do something..
```

Is there any edge cases or scenarios in which doing this would be bad practice or result in different results than just checking the length of the array?

Comment: It would be more efficient to check the length because in situations where there are array items, the value of the first item would need to be resolved with index checking whereas it wouldn't with a length check.

Comment: A non-empty array can have no element at index 0: `const array = []; array[1] = 1;`. No element exists at index 0, but the array has length 2 and an element at index 1. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8qeyk5bu/

Comment: But you can check `if (array.length)` to shorten your code.

Answer (score 1):

Even if in most cases the two methods will produce the same result, I strongly recommend using the first one. The only way of telling if an array is empty or not, is by checking its length.

```js
if (array.length) {
  // array is not empty
}
```

Here are an example where the second method would not work:

```js
const array = [null, "I think", "therefore I am"]

console.log(array.length) // 3
console.log(array[0]) // null, and will evaluate to false
```

Another case that might occur more often:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

delete array[0]

console.log(array.length) // 5
console.log(array[0]) // undefined, and will evaluate to false
```

### Performance

Interestingly, if the array is empty, it's faster to check if the first element exists:

```js
let array = []

console.time('lengthCheck')
console.log(array.length)
console.timeEnd("lengthCheck")
// about 0.06s in my browser

console.time('itemCheck')
console.log(array[0])
console.timeEnd("itemCheck")
// about 0.025s in my browser
```

Answer (score 0):

For an empty array, `array[0]` will throw an index_out_of_bounds exception, whereas `array.length` will return 0.